# How to avoid Open xml tag on its own line

Tags: xslt

I have an XML structure as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cl:doc identifier="ISBN" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core cendoc.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cl="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<cl:chapter identifier="ch01">
<cl:opener identifier="ch06_opn">
<cl:introduction identifier="ch06_int">
<cl:list identifier="tu_1" list-style="Unformatted" item-length="long">
<cl:item identifier="tu_2"><cl:para identifier="ch01_dum_2">Solubility</cl:para></cl:item>
<cl:item identifier="tu_3"><cl:para identifier="ch01_dum_3">Polarity</cl:para></cl:item>
</cl:list></cl:introduction></cl:opener></cl:chapter></cl:doc>
```

When I transform this above xml using XSLT, I got the below output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cl:doc identifier="ISBN" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core cendoc.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cl="http://xml.cengage-learning.com/cendoc-core" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><cl:chapter identifier="ch01">
<cl:opener identifier="ch06_opn">
<cl:introduction identifier="ch06_int"><cl:list identifier="tu_1" list-style="Unformatted" item-length="long">
<cl:item identifier="tu_2"><cl:para identifier="ch01_dum_2">Solubility</cl:para></cl:item>
<cl:item identifier="tu_3"><cl:para identifier="ch01_dum_3">Polarity</cl:para></cl:item></cl:list></cl:introduction></cl:opener></cl:chapter></cl:doc>
```

Here, the opening tag `<cl:opener identifier="ch06_opn">` alone comes on separate line. This result me to have the blank line after doing the conversion.

I need this `<cl:opener identifier="ch06_opn">` tag must be run-on with either its previous line or to the next line.

Can anybody help me how this can be achieved through XSLT.

Thanks,
Gopal

Comment: Remove the newline in your XSLT file at the end of the line where you are emitting `<cl:opener>`. Put the following logic immediately following `<cl:opener>`.

Comment: **1.** Why is this a problem? **2.** If it *is* a problem, show us how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your XSLT it's difficult to be certain, but it sounds like your XSLT is copying over the whitespace in the source into the output.

The quickest way to prevent that is to put

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

or alternatively

```
<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

This removes all whitespace, but you can of course be more specific about the whitespace you're removing, such as

```
<xsl:template match="cl:opener/text()[1][not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

to remove just the whitespace after that opening element tag- this matches the first text node within `cl:opener` if it's whitespace only, and outputs nothing in it's place.